# How to find the cause of a Maven build error?

Tags: maven

I try to make a local Maven build.

```
% mvn help:effective-settings 

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Downloading: http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom

[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for example.components.discovery:example-app:01-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.2.RELEASE from/to nexus (http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Access denied to: http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 12, column 10

@ 

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]   

[ERROR]   The project example.components.discovery:example-app:01-SNAPSHOT (/Users/me/workspace/example-app/pom.xml) has 1 error

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for example.components.discovery:example-app:99.99.99-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.2.RELEASE from/to nexus (http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Access denied to: http://example.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 12, column 10 -> [Help 2]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Some noticeable facts:

- I get the same error on other projects with the same Spring dependency.
- Co-workers don’t have this problem when they run a Maven build of the project.
- Before introducing Nexus, the Maven build was run successfully, and so did for other Spring projects.
- If there were some syntax errors in the settings.xml, the above error would show first and follow by complaints of syntax errors in the settings.xml.
- My settings.xml seems to have the same structure as my co-worker’s who can run the Maven build successfully, the user credentials are different, of course.

The above facts eliminate all possible causes stated in the help 1 document. Among 6 possible causes stated in the help 2 document, the only possible cause is #4 given the above facts. We have a tool to generate the settins.xml file and use Maven encryption to encrypt the password for the file. I don't know how to verify whether the encrypted password is correct or not. Any other possible causes?

Comment: Two possiblities: `Access denied to: http://` - should it be `https`? If that's not it, there is either something wrong with the credentials setup, or perhaps your account is missing a role or few for Nexus.

Comment: Well no, the error is pretty clear. On trying to download from Nexus you're getting `ReasonPhrase:Forbidden`. Can you login to the Nexus WebUI and validate that the exact dependency is present there? Then your access credentials in settings.xml are invalid.

Comment: On the encrypted password; ideally you know your master password, then you can encrypt your known nexus password again and see if the value matches what is currently configured.

Comment: @slindenau I can sign into the Nexus with my user credentials on its web page. My password in the settings.xml is encrypted with the Maven encryption algorithm (as I am told). And the encrypted password isn't the same each time. That lets me wonder how Maven encryption works. We have a tool to generate the settings.xml file. The Spring parent dependency isn't in the Nexus. To my understanding, Maven looks for a dependency based on the pom.xml in the order of local, Nexus, and remote. In this case, if one isn't in Nexus, Maven would try to download from the remote.